# Write To Text Box From Query String

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have my query string down, and have verified that all values are being passed as they should be.  Even if you look in the address bar it shows the appropriate values, but they are not being written to the page itself.

```
string pagetoload = "www.nonono12323hamarabi2323.html";
string bld = "FranklinJonesSmith";
Response.Redirect(pagetoload+"?BuildingName="+bld);
```

And this is the html for the field buildingname

```
<div style="width: 10px;"></div>
<input id="BuildingName" name="BuildingName" maxlength="255" type="text" style="width:240px;">
```

**EDIT**
and if I look in the address bar when the page loads it shows the correct value that I am trying to pass.  The address bar reads:

```
www.nonono12323hamarabi2323.html?BuildingName=FranklinJonesSmith
```

**EDIT 2**
Thanks to @RJ Cuthbertson I now have a better understanding and realize that simplay passing the querystring to the page does not populate the textboxes themselves.  
I am using webforms and am launching an order page using `Response.Redirect` so I do not have a way of accessing the C# Page_Load Event to do something like

```
BuildingName.Text=Request.QueryString["bld"];
```

So am I safe to say I need to research the JavaScrip methods mentioned below?

Comment: Query string arguments don't automagically map to inputs on the page, you have to set the value of the input.

Comment: @RJCuthbertson - isn't BuildingName the input that I need the value FranklinJonesSmith mapped to?

Comment: How are you trying to set the value of the input? Are you trying to do it server-side or client-side?

Comment: @RJCuthbertson - Either way will suffice.  I just need to be able to click the button and the page load with the values being passed to it already populated.

Comment: @SimonParis: Regarding your **Edit 2**: Why would `Page_Load` not be triggered? Is the redirect to a static page (i.e. html)?

Comment: You probably aren't hitting Page_Load due to caching. A redirect should still trigger that event. See http://codeverge.com/asp.net.web-forms/page_load-not-firing-after-response.redirec/400354

Comment: @SaniHuttunen - Yes, the end of the page I am launching is .html is that what you are asking?

Comment: @SimonParis: Yes that was what I was asking. Then the solution is to use javascript to get the values from the querystring and populate the controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query string arguments are a way to pass data in your URL, but they don't automatically map their values to elements in the DOM.

If you're trying to do this client-side, with JavaScript you can get the query string from the `location.search` property.

To parse the query string, there are plenty of implementations [on the web](http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/3-ways-to-parse-a-query-string-in-a-url/) and [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript).

Then you'll need to set the value to your input control:

```
document.getElementById('BuildingName').value = yourVariableWithTheValueFromTheQueryString;
```

Comment: using webforms.  See my edit #2, I now have somewhat of a better understanding of the issue.

Comment: Cuthebertson - where would I place the JavaScript piece to perform this?

Comment: At the bottom of the page in a script element just inside the closing tag of the body element.